Problems when trying to install the python package mip
I am trying to install module mip into my python development environment. I use Spyder IDE(V. 5.4.3). I followed all the recommended steps to integrate a separated Pyton enviroment such it is compatible with spyder:

Installed a separated python environment: - custom Python 3.12.1
Installed the "spyder-kernels" that will make the separated Python
environment compatible with Spyder (python -m pip install
"spyder-kernels"==2.2.*)
From the Spyder preference menu, selected the following interpreter:
C:\Program Files\Python Software Foundation\Python
3.12.1\python.exe
From a Spyder console typed the command: pip install mip.

And now I am facing the following problem:
Collecting mipNote: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

    Using cached mip-1.14.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (21 kB)
    Collecting cffi==1.15.0 (from mip)
    Using cached cffi-1.15.0.tar.gz (484 kB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Installing backend dependencies: started
    Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
    Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\\program files\\python software         foundation\\python 3.12.1\\lib\\site-packages (from cffi==1.15.0-\>mip) (2.22)
    Using cached mip-1.14.2-py3-none-any.whl (15.3 MB)
    Building wheels for collected packages: cffi
    Building wheel for cffi (pyproject.toml): started
    Building wheel for cffi (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
    Failed to build cffi
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error

    Building wheel for cffi (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
    exit code: 1

    \[37 lines of output\]
    _configtest.c
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
    creating build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\\cffi
    copying cffi\\api.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\\cffi
    copying cffi\\backend_ctypes.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\\cffi
    copying cffi\\cffi_opcode.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\\cffi
    copying cffi\\commontypes.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\\cffi
    copying cffi\\cparser.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\\cffi
    copying cffi\\error.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\\cffi
    copying cffi\\ffiplatform.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\\cffi
    copying cffi\\lock.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\\cffi
    copying cffi\\model.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\\cffi
    copying cffi\\pkgconfig.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\\cffi
    copying cffi\\recompiler.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\\cffi
    copying cffi\\setuptools_ext.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\\cffi
    copying cffi\\vengine_cpy.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\\cffi
    copying cffi\\vengine_gen.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\\cffi
    copying cffi\\verifier.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\\cffi
    copying cffi_init_.py -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\\cffi
    copying cffi_cffi_include.h -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\\cffi
    copying cffi\\parse_c_type.h -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\\cffi
    copying cffi_embedding.h -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\\cffi
    copying cffi_cffi_errors.h -\> build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\\cffi
    running build_ext
    building '\_cffi_backend' extension
    creating build\\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312
    creating build\\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\\Release
    creating build\\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\\Release\\c
    creating build\\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\\Release\\c\\libffi_x86_x64
    "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual     Studio\\2022\\Preview\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic/libffi_x86_x64 "-IC:\\Program Files\\Python Software Foundation\\Python 3.12.1\\include" "-IC:\\Program Files\\Python Software Foundation\\Python  3.12.1\\Include" "-IC:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual  Studio\\2022\\Preview\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\include" "-IC:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Preview\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\ATLMFC\\include" "-IC:\\Program  Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Preview\\VC\\Auxiliary\\VS\\include"  /Tcc/\_cffi_backend.c /Fobuild\\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\\Release\\c/\_cffi_backend.obj
\_cffi_backend.c
    C:\\Program Files\\Python Software Foundation\\Python 3.12.1\\include\\pyconfig.h(59):   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual   Studio\\2022\\Preview\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with   exit code 2
    \[end of output\]

    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for cffi
    ERROR: Could not build wheels for cffi, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based   projects

First I tried to install other modules (like openpyxl), without problems.
Then I thought to re-install Microsoft Visual Studio using Visual Studio installer checking that my installation included the "Desktop development with C++" workload installed.
But no changes. Same results as above.
